# What is up with the bigfoot tag?

Tags: bug

I like to write the tag descriptions (though I still have to get them reviewed). I was just doing that and I saw bigfoot. I right click to open the new tab. I go over and see no [questions with the bigfoot tag](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bigfoot?sort=newest&pageSize=15). Why is this tag here with no questions tagged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where did you see that? [bigfoot](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bigfoot) is not listed under our [tags page](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tags). It is actually a tag synonym of [sasquatch](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sasquatch), so all questions tagged with it are automatically retagged as the latter.